# Edit cells with number values using JXL

Tags: java, numbers, jxl

```
 sheetToEdit.addCell(new Label(j, i, s[i]));
```

In the above line, Label takes only the string values. But I want to add the cells in the rows with the number (double) values.

Is there any other method in JXL by which I can add cells with number values.

Answer (score 0):

Use Number instead of Label for cells containing numeric values.  So you might want to instantiate ...

```
Number(int c, int r, double val, CellFormat st)
```

Where c is column, r row, val is the double value you are interested in setting and st (which is optional, you only have to use the first three parameters) is obviously the cell formatting.